# BarChart - Maintain ChartElementFunction when changing PlotRange

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts

Here is a `BarChart` of some data

```
data = {90, 91, 95, 103, 107, 102, 107, 105, 98, 96}

{90, 91, 95, 103, 107, 102, 107, 105, 98, 96}

BarChart[data, ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleRectangle"]
```

[image]

When I add `PlotRange` the color goes away.

```
BarChart[data, ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleRectangle", 
 PlotRange -> {80, 120}]
```

[image]

Is it possible to work around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use a custom `ChartElementFunction` to clip the rectangles:

```
ClearAll[cEF]
cEF[cedf_: "GradientScaleRectangle", o: OptionsPattern[]][d_, pr_] := 
 Block[{Charting`ChartStyleInformation}, 
   Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoundingBox"] = 
      {{.5, Length @ d + .5}, {pr[[1]], Max @ d}};
   ChartElementDataFunction[cedf, o][{#[[1]], Clip[#[[2]], pr]}, ##2]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
data = {90, 91, 95, 103, 107, 102, 107, 105, 98, 96};
plotrange = {80, 120};

BarChart[data, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF[][data, plotrange], 
 ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["A", "J"],  
 PlotRange -> plotrange, 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

Use `cEF["GradientScaleRectangle", "ColorScheme" -> "Rainbow"][data, plotrange]` to get:

[image]

```
BarChart[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
    cEF["GlassRectangle", "GradientOrigin" -> Top][data, {75, 110}], 
 ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["A", "J"],  
 PlotRange -> {75, 110}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[data, 
 ChartStyle -> (Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}]] & /@ {"Lena", "Mandrill"}),
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF["TextureRectangle"][data, {70, 110}], 
 ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["A", "J"],  
 PlotRange -> {70, 110}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative approach using modified input data and custom ticks and plot range padding:

```
plotrange = {80, 120};
data2 = data - plotrange[[1]];
plotrange2 = {0, - Subtract @@ plotrange};
padding = plotrange2[[2]] - Max @ data2;

BarChart[Thread[Tooltip[data2, data]],
 ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleRectangle",
 ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["A", "J"],
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, padding}},
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[plotrange2, plotrange]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Results look great! I can more or less follow your code but am lost at the last part. The documention has two examples of `ChartElementDataFunction` in the `BarChart` documention but is not mentioned in Details or Options. Could you expound on the arguments in this experssion?  `ChartElementDataFunction[cedf, o][{#[[1]], Clip[#[[2]], pr]}, ##2]`. In particular ##2, #1 and #2. Thank you

Comment: @JackLaVigne, `cEF` can also be wriiten as ``ClearAll[cEF2];
cEF2[cedf_: "GradientScaleRectangle", o : OptionsPattern[]][d_, pr_][
  box : {{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, value_,  metadata___] := (Charting`ChartStyleInformation[ "BoundingBox"] = {{.5, Length@d + .5}, {pr[[1]], Max@d}};  ChartElementDataFunction[cedf, o][{box[[1]], Clip[box[[2]], pr]}, 
   val, metadata])``, which, I hope, clarifies the correspondence between the slots (`#1 <-> box`, `#2 <-> value`, and `##2 <-> second and later arguments`) .

Comment: Thank you, I understand better now. Something odd that happens to me with either form is I get an error "Set::write: Tag Charting`ChartStyleInformation in Charting`ChartStyleInformation[BoundingBox] is Protected." after having defined cEF and run `BarChart[
 data,
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF[][data, {80, 120}],
 PlotRange -> {80, 120}
 ]` the first time. The picture is good but the error appears. The second time I run it the error is absent. Does that happen to you?

Comment: @JackLaVigne, updated with a variant that does not produce an error message.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {90, 91, 95, 103, 107, 102, 107, 105, 98, 96};
Show[BarChart[data,
  ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleRectangle"],
 PlotRange -> {80, 120}]
```

[image]

Plotting the colours blue to orange by adjusting the data and tick labels.

```
data = {90, 91, 95, 103, 107, 102, 107, 105, 98, 96} - 80;
Show[BarChart[data,
  ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleRectangle",
  Ticks -> {Automatic,
    {{0, 80}, {10, 90}, {20, 100}, {30, 110}, {40, 120}}}],
 PlotRange -> {0, 40}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris. Now colors show up but the color range of the upper quarter of the plot. Would prefer the colors to be be blue to orange.

Comment: Perfect. Simple subtraction on the data and Tick modifications works great. When I put a Frame around it there was an initial failure. Discovered that with Frame must modify FrameTicks (seems straightforward). Thank you.